# how to configure ecosystem.config.js file for next.js on apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, next.js, server, pm2

am trying to deploy nextjs app on apache using pm2.
I have installed latest versions of node, pm2. and apache is configured as reverse proxy.
but when am trying to start daemon process, it is not doing it. I cloned a project from github and ran 'npm run build, which created .next file and in that file, I created ecosystem.config.js file for pm2, it looks like this :

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "nextjs-app",
    script: "npm",
    args: "run build",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "production"
    }
  }]
};
```

but when I ran `pm2 start npm -- start`  , terminal is giving me respone like this:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/georgianar/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

but when I try to see list of process, there is none, and when user tries to enter the website, site log shows that there is no service on port 3000

```
(111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (localhost:3000) failed
```

and

```
AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

I dont know why, any idea why it is doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a ecosystem file if you just want to run the already deployed and builded next app in your server with pm2.

Just run from your project root folder:

```
pm2 start npm --name "app_name" -- start
```

Comment: but it does not work, server says that service is unavailable(no process is active)

Comment: @gogagoglika if you run "pm2 ls" you do not have any service started?

If you have one, try with "pm2 logs" to see what is going on.

Comment: no there is no service

Comment: Try first to run "npm start" on your project and see if it is working, then try to run "pm2 start app.js" (create an app.js file that does nothing), so you can see where the problem is.